Keyword expansion in migration from SVN to GIT
I'm using svn-all-fast-export to migrate from SVN to git. Unfortunately it replaces all keywords like $Date: 2023-02-01 10:32:01 +0100 (Wed, 01 Feb 2023)$ to $Date$. Is there an option to surpress that?
Googling and browsing through the source code of svn-all-fast-export did not help :-(

Are you using bash?

Yes, Debian WSL

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261735/118498 "If you want to prevent parameter expansion, you need to use quoting, like single quote '$b' or escaping \$b"

I call the script in bash like "svn-all-fast-export --stats --debug-rules --resume-from 1 --rules rules/myRule.rules" so there is nothing with escaping. svn-all-fast-export does it on its own during conversion

@BastianCramer I don't think it's possible. SVN stores keywords unexpanded and expands them on checkout. svn-all-fast-export exports what it sees — unexpanded keywords. You can do keywords expansion in Git, again only on checkout. See https://github.com/turon/git-rcs-keywords and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_ident . But please be warned it's not recommended: https://archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq.html#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F

Perhaps a run of git filter-repo to replace all those values would do.
